# Converting raw video fails

Tags: c#, video, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm trying to convert a raw (y4m) video to a more standard format. I'm following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) on MSDN, which uses Windows.Media.Transcoding, and which works for wmv to mp4.
It doesn't, however, work for y4m to mp4, failing with a `TranscodeFailureReason.Unknown` .

How do I transcode it? (With the builtin managed methods only. No 3rd party libraries. No C++.)

Comment: Winrt .net framework doesn't provide such functionality. The only way is to use c/c++ libraries through interop library (for example ffmpeg).

Comment: The question is not about .net.